# Netbeans-19: Change file associations in typeMap.json

Tags: express, netbeans, express-handlebars

I am working in Windows 10 using Netbeans-19 IDE with a javascript/html project that uses **express-handlebars v 7.1**.

I naively changed the file type designation from **.handlebars** to **.hndlbrs** in my **configure.js** file, and in the IDE using **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Files**. I added the **.hndlbrs** extension as **text/html** so the IDE would format these as HTML files for easier editing. But when I run the project I get an error page that says it cannot load my *"...views/layouts/main.handlebars"* file.

The file in *"...view/layouts"* is named **main.hndlbrs**. I note that the file type listed in **...\NetBeans-19\netbeans\webcommon\typescript-lsp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typesMap.json** for handlebars files is *"handlebars"*, not *"hndlbrs"*. I can't edit that file, and I do not find anything in the IDE that lets me change that file association. Does anyone know how to change that file association?